# How do you get +150% experience tickets?

Tags: splatoon-2

Or +100% tickets, for that matter!

I don't think I've gotten one in the single player mode. Still, even if they are there, there should be another way to get them, right? Since those don't respawn. (I think there may have been a single +100% ticket in single player, though.)

I've played quite a bit of Salmon Run, but that only seems to give you +50% experience tickets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get tickets in Salmon Run you'll most likely get the +100% and +150% experience tickets in a super bonus, not a regular bonus. You'll need to play quite a bit of Salmon Run to get it because you need to get 600p to get it, and even then, there's only a 50% chance you'll get a ticket.

Answer (score 2):

You can also get them though Octo-Expansion. When you beat Octo-Expansion, There will be a vending machine in Central Station. By using 15000 points, you can get items including 50%, 100% and 150% tickets.

`